# Questions about the concurrency‘s synchronized, how it works, what is the scope

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

I am trying to understand how java's synchronized works, and I have read some document, but would somebody helps check the correctness and also the questions
For the code block

```
public class MyWaitNotify3{

  MonitorObject myMonitorObject = new MonitorObject();
  boolean wasSignalled = false;

  public void doWait(){
    synchronized(myMonitorObject){
      while(!wasSignalled){
        try{
          myMonitorObject.wait();
         } catch(InterruptedException e){...}
      }
      //clear signal and continue running.
      wasSignalled = false;
    }
  }

  public void doNotify(){
    synchronized(myMonitorObject){
      wasSignalled = true;
      myMonitorObject.notify();
    }
  }
}
```

```
MyWaitNotify3 inst1 = new MyWaitNotify3();
MyWaitNotify3 inst2 = new MyWaitNotify3();
```

If we create one thread with inst1, another thread with inst2
Then if we do thread1.doWait(), then the thread will hangs at the line  "myMonitorObject.wait();"
The question is that the lock in scope of "dowait", "synchronized(myMonitorObject)", will this blocks thread2 from acquire the lock in "doNotify()"??

From my understanding, since they are two instances, thread2 cannot acquire the "synchronized(myMonitorObject)" in doWait, but would acquire the "synchronized(myMonitorObject)" in doNotify. Is that correct?

What will happens if we define

```
MyWaitNotify3 inst1 = new MyWaitNotify3();
thread1 = new Thread(inst1, "A");
thread2 = new Thread(inst1, "B");
```

Comment: Wait method Javadoc: This method causes the current thread (call it T) to place itself in the wait set for this object and then to relinquish any and all synchronization claims on this object.
So thread2 wouldn't have to wait

Comment: @NathanHughes well, I could see he shares the same instance to both these threads, MyWaitNotify3 inst1 = new MyWaitNotify3();
thread1 = new Thread(inst1, "A");
thread2 = new Thread(inst1, "B");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is that the lock in scope of "dowait", "synchronized(myMonitorObject)", will this blocks thread2 from acquire the lock in "doNotify()"??

No, it won't. A thread will release the lock for the critical section (`synchronized`-block) when it goes into waiting state with `wait` in `doWait`. In that time, another thread can acquire that lock for the critical section in `doNotify`. When the waiting thread leaves the waiting state, it has to acquire the lock again.

However, when the thread in `doWait` is running, i.e. not blocked in `wait`, it will of course hold the current lock for the section, i.e. `myMonitorObject`, which will block another thread in `doNotify`.

You can imagine `wait` to be a point where a thread leaves the critical section, releases the lock, which enables others to acquire it, and as an entrance point for the critical section where the thread has to re-acquire the lock for it, which involves blocking.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. So would you know what will happen if there are 100 threads called doWait and wait in the functions wait(), do we need to run doNotify with another 100 threads to release the 100 "waits"?

Comment: @anoobontheway There can always be just one thread in the section. Therefore, if multiple threads are waked, the first one to enter the section initially will set `wasSignalled` to `false`. All the other threads will go right back into `wait`. Because `doNotify` is the only place where `wasSignalled` is set to `true` and always only *one* waiter can use that condition, you will have to have the same amout of notifiers as waiters. In short: yes.